# Get JSON data on HTML Form Submit with HTTP POST

Tags: html, json, forms, post, content-type

I am trying to get JSON data on click of a button

Heres the HTML for it

```
<html>
<title> </title>
<body>  
<h2> Main API - http://api.kalendern.se/api</h3>
<form method="get" enctype="application/json; charset=utf-8" 
    action="http://api.example.com" border="1">
    <input type=submit value="Show Main API"> </td>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting XML data.

However I need JSON data. How can I achieve this?

Is the enctype I am setting same as the content-type?

If not what is the difference and what is the right value to get the JSON data?

Thanks

Dev.

Comment: To set the content-type on the HTTP request(get/post), I need to do it in JavaScript or any other scripting language. Apparently you cannot do it in plain HTML. Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I need JSON data. How can I achieve this?

To get it directly, it depends on the service. The URL to the documentation you provided leads to a 404.

To get it indirectly, you could run a server side process to fetch the XML and convert it to JSON, then talk to your server side process instead of the remote API. Likewise, you could use a third party service that can do that (YQL will, I think).

> Is the enctype I am setting same as the content-type?

More or less … but of the data the browser **sends**. Only the values "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "multipart/form-data" are well supported.